# how to make detection of external hard disk & retrive data from it

Tags: usb, hard-drive

Previously I am using Ubuntu 12.04, then switch to 14.04, and then 15.04. My external hard disk is not detected in 15.04, however, detected in previous versions. I have made GUI for detection of external devices which is as below:

```
[[[Model : TOSHIBA MK5065GSX(GJ003A) Size: %)) GB Serial umber: 7OUEB4PWB Assessment : Disk is OK, one bad sector Volume 500 GB Device: /dev/sdb]]]
```

How to make it detected and/or retrieve data from it?

---

I'm not very conversant in Linux. (is there any . or , in the 2nd and 3rd command? ) The 1st two command gives the following outputs, please suggest which one is my ext hdd - is that sda2, should I write sda2 within **? :

```
[[Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x029a0299
Device     Boot     Start       End Sectors    Size  Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63 102398309 102398247  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       102398371 625139711 522741341 249.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       102398373 184313744  81915372  39.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       184313808 245746304  61432497  29.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       245747712 246919167   1171456   572M 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       246921216 250824703   3903488   1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9       387545088 625139711 237594624 113.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda10      250826752 387536895 136710144  65.2G 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

durjoy@durjoy-Aspire-4736Z:~$ sudo mkdir /media/external_drive .
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.’: File exists

durjoy@durjoy-Aspire-4736Z:~$ sudo mkdir /media/external_drive
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/external_drive’: File exists
```

3rd command gives the following output:

```
durjoy@durjoy-Aspire-4736Z:~$ sudo mount -t W95 Ext'd (LBA) /dev/sda2 /media/external_drive
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually mount the external drive from a command prompt. First, identify the drive with:

`sudo fdisk -l` ,

then, once you've identified your drive, create a mount point for it:

`sudo mkdir /media/external_drive` .

Lastly, mount the drive itself with:

`sudo mount -t *hard drive type* /dev/sd*letter* /media/external_drive` ,

substituting your values in between the ** as appropriate.

Once you've mounted the drive, you can explore it with 'cd', like:

`sudo cd /media/external_drive` .

To `umount` the drive do:

`sudo umount /media/external_drive` .

Keep in mind, you can't `umount` a drive if you are actually in the mounted directory (or sub-directory(s)).

Comment: I am not very conversant in Linux. The 1st two command lines give the following output.

Comment: @DurjoyMajumder, I've updated the commands. `fdisk` will tell you what drives exist; `mkdir` will create a mount point, and the final command--`mount`-- will mount the partition you designate to that directory. The '.' was a period meaning end of sentence, which is why you received the first error. The second is because the directory now exists. Based on the size of the partitions, and the way Windows assigns partitions be default, I think you do need to mount `/dev/sda2` .

Comment: What to write *hard drive type*? please guide.